# Windows azure vm re-routing

Tags: windows, azure

I would like to cancel my windows azure vm subsrcription. How do I go about in re-route the .cloudapp.net name space to my new local vm ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't!

You don't own the cloudapp.net domain and you never had. This domain is owned and managed by Microsoft. You just need to buy your own domain and route it to your local VM. There is no other way!

Comment: Can I buy a XXXXX.cloudapp.net  domain ?

Comment: XXXXX is a hostname within the cloudapp.net domain which as @astaykov said is owned by Microsoft.  Typically you'd buy your own domain and point a CNAME to the cloudapp.net instance you're using.  As you haven't done that you don't have that option.